# opengl pixel data to jpeg

Tags: opengl, jpeg, libjpeg

Any C++ examples available to convert raw pixel data obtained from glReadPixels to JPEG format and back?

Comment: Why has this got a JPEG2000 tag on it?  JPEG and JPEG2K are entirely different beasts.

Comment: can we do this in jpeg2k as well? I have never used jpeg2k. Any pointers?

Comment: jpeg2k is just a different lossy image format.  Doing what you want "in jpeg2k" would be the same as any other format, assuming the library you've chosen to use supports it (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000 for a list of supporting libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick library to convert raw data to the jpeg image data, and opposite. Using the same library, you can convert jpeg image data into raw (RGB) data.

Answer (score 1):

Use an external library for that.

I'll recommend [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/), your number one Swiss Army Knife for handling image files. You'll just need to

- create an RGB image in memory via DevIL,
- call `glReadPixels` to fill your DevIL image with pixels read from the GL framebuffer,
- call `ilSaveImage("foo.jpg")` to save the file. You can also use `bmp`, `png` and a handful more - the format will get autodetected from the file name.

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if OpenGL has support for dealing with JPEG images.  It's not what the library is really for.

Once you've got access to the pixel data, you should be able to use easily [OpenCV](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/docs/1.0/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm#highgui_loadsave) to write the image to JPEG (or any other format), though.  Here's some pseudo-code to get you going.

```
/*
 * On Linux, compile with:
 *
 * g++ -Wall -ggdb -I. -I/usr/include/opencv -L /usr/lib -lm -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux filename.cpp -o filename.out
 */

#include <cv.h>    
#include <highgui.h>

/*
 * Your image dimensions.
 */
int width;
int height;

CvSize size = cvSize(width, height);

/*
 * Create 3-channel image, unsigned 8-bit per channel.
 */
IplImage *image = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
{
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int g;
    unsigned int b;

    /*
     * Call glReadPixels, grab your RGB data.
     * Keep in mind that OpenCV stores things in BGR order.
     */
    CvScalar bgr = cvScalar(b, g, r);
    cvSet2D(image, i, j, bgr);
}

cvSaveImage("filename.jpg", image);
cvReleaseImage(&image);
```

Other libraries for dealing with JPEG also exist, if you look around.

Comment: I was thinking may be libjpeg.

Comment: Yes, any imaging library will do.  It's a pretty routine thing to do so I doubt the code will look much different.

Comment: I could not find any in memory compression function in libjpeg. Does any c++ code exist that display in memory compression/decompression (as opposed to writing to file)

Comment: You could save the image to a file and then read it back into memory, if you really wanted to.  Or, if you were really desperate, you could cannibalise the libjpeg code to expose the encoded bitstream before it is written to a file.  But why would you want that, anyway?

Comment: Also, have a look at OpenCV's imencode function: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html